# Export Sharepoint 2016 list to excel that contain managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, export-to-excel, managed-metadata-column

Good day, my client wants to export a custom list in SharePoint 2016 that contains managed metadata.
When I export the list, it shows the 'id;# with name' value e.g. '35;#Legal Department' in the excel column, but when my client exports it, it only shows '35;#' - without the wording.
Any idea what the problem could be or how to allow the client to export the list and see the word/name next to the number?